# New domain does not get verified. Error- URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My Facebook app runs on a webpage. I am changing my app's domain from `<app-name>.glitch.me` to `<user-name>.github.io/<app-name>`. I added my new domain everywhere required (see screenshots below).

- In Basic Settings, I added my new domain along with my old domain.
  [image: image showing app domains]
- In Basic Settings, in the end, I switched my old address to the new address.
  [image: image showing website]
- In Advanced Settings, under Domain Manager, I added my new domain along with my old domain.
  [image: image showing domain manager]

Even after changing all these settings, I can not log in from my new domain. When I try to login from the new domain, I get this error:

```
URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.
```

Other settings are not affecting anything as the login system works absolutely fine on my old webpage. I have also checked that the URLs are typed correctly. Did I miss adding my new URL somewhere? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the login system to work, you need to specify your URL in the Facebook Login Settings.
Adding the domain here fixed my issue:
[image]